# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my Post Card UI where I get the error

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../models/user_models.dart';
import '../provider/user_provider.dart';

class PostCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final snap;

 const PostCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.snap,
  
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PostCard> createState() => _PostCardState();
}

class _PostCardState extends State<PostCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final User? user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 10,
      ),
      child: Container(
        child: Column(children: [
          Container(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                // CircleAvatar(
                //   backgroundImage: NetworkImage(widget.snap['profileUrl'])),
                
                //  Text(widget.snap['username']),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    widget.snap['username'],
                    // 'username',
                    style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.stars_rounded,
                          color: CupertinoColors.systemYellow,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '3 stars',
                          style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.systemYellow),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),

                  // SizedBox.shrink(),

                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.comment_outlined,
                        color: CupertinoColors.systemYellow,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '3 comment',
                        style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.systemYellow),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          Divider(
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.stars_outlined,
                    color: CupertinoColors.systemYellow,
                    size: 35,
                  )),
              Spacer(),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.comment_outlined,
                    color: CupertinoColors.systemYellow,
                    size: 35,
                  )),
              Spacer(),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.share_outlined,
                    color: CupertinoColors.systemYellow,
                    size: 35,
                  )),
            ],
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}



This is my error page.[enter image description here][1]

I want to solve this error please help me, I've been here for 3
```

days .I don't have no idea why I get this error and I write this
style of widget in the project that I've wrote in early flutter. And I am new here so I don't know exactly how to ask question actually and I am non-English-native speaker and I am not fluent in English that why I can make some grammar and some vocabulary .If I did mistakes please forgive me .Thanks

Here is my getUser File

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class User {
  final String email;
  final String uid;
  final String profileUrl;
  final String username;
  final String bio;
  final List followers;
  final List following;
  final List stars;

  const User({
    required this.email,
    required this.uid,
    required this.profileUrl,
    required this.username,
    required this.bio,
    required this.followers,
    required this.following,
    required this.stars,
  });
  static User fromSnap(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    var snapshot =
        snap.data() != null ? snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic> : {};

    return User(
      stars: snapshot['stars'] ?? '',
      email: snapshot['email'] ?? '',
      uid: snapshot['uid'] ?? '0000000',
      profileUrl: snapshot['profileUrl'] ?? '',
      username: snapshot['username'] ?? '',
      bio: snapshot['bio'] ?? '',
      followers: snapshot['followers'] ?? [],
      following: snapshot['following'] ?? [],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "username": username,
        "uid": uid,
        "email": email,
        "profileUrl": profileUrl,
        "bio": bio,
        "followers": followers,
        "following": following,
        "stars": stars,
      };
}
```

Comment: Add a dot to string   your Variavle add   EX .toString()

Comment: I've tried to add .toString() but I still get the same error. Anyway,Thanks for your help @ kk web

Comment: widget.snap[0]['username'] try  this  type

Comment: As you said ,@kk web, I tried it ,But I get this error Exception has occurred.
RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)

Comment: I'll put it in  my question .Please help me . @Darshan Kachhadiya

Comment: Try replacing this line `stars: snapshot['stars'] ?? '',` with `stars: snapshot['stars'] ?? [],` in your getUser file.

Comment: Hello, `snap` is not typed so it ends up being treated as a `dynamic` by Dart. Can you be more specific wrt the type of this field?

Comment: @pixel Yes, I try it as you said ,but I still get the same error.

Comment: Finally I figured out where I get this error and solve it ,Thanks for you all